# php fopen is not working (always null)

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fopen

I have the following code in a "function" file [2] in my project. It can be called for multiple types of reports in my project. The $name comes from the reports pages using the $thePDFFileName [1]:

```
[1] $pdf->Output($thePDFFileName);
...
[2] $f=fopen($name,'wb');
if(!$f)
{
    $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
}
fwrite($f,$this->buffer,strlen($this->buffer));
fclose($f);
...
[1] FunctionSendFile::sendPDFFile($thePDFFileName );
```

Example: $thePDFFileName = tmp/[Filename]_19-11-2013.pdf

What's strange is before it was working for all my reports, now all of a sudden it always returns null (empty) for $f=fopen($name,'wb'); and I have no idea why. I tried removing the if condition to force the file being created, and it makes a pdf file of 0 bytes (I'm assuming because fopen() fails).

Has anyone seen this happen before and know how to fix it? I'm not sure what i've done to make all the pdf files stop working...

NOTE: I am trying to create these files and save them in a certain location. I'm not trying to find and open files that already exist!

Comment: are you sure it's null? fopen cannot return null. it returns either a handle, or a boolean FALSE to indicate failure. You should have `$f = fopen(...) or die("Unable to fopen()")`

Comment: I guess it's false. I have made an error_log output of $f and gotten and blank (empty) output.

Comment: `error_get_last()` should help